# Flask resets the connection instead of returning a 413, when the file is to big

Tags: python, flask

When `MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH`is definded, Flask should return an 413, but in my case it resets the connection with this error: `Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.`

I attached a example built upon the file upload pattern from Flask.

I use Chrome 15.0.874.5.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from werkzeug import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif','bib','mp3'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <p><input type=file name=file>
         <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''

@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)

@app.errorhandler(413)
def file_to_big(e):
    return 'File to big'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is only a problem using the Flask Dev sever. When I went live on a lighttp the redirect worked.

Comment: Any idea about gevent servers?

Comment: No, never heard of gevent servers.

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49332379/5511849) for more info.

Comment: i'm using uwsgi with nginx as proxy and still get the same error

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar issue where uploading a file to a flask dev server gave me the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in chrome.

Basically, in the receiving view on the server, I check if the user's session has expired, and if it has, I return a redirect. For some reason this causes a connection reset. I'm guessing this is because the browser is still trying to send the file but the server doesn't want it (though I can't back that up with evidence).

Thought I'd put this here for anyone who lands here like I did.

Comment: I have the exact same situation and problem, have you found any solution?

Comment: Figurated a way to solve it! In my case i wanted to checked if the user was authorized to upload files to the server before doing it, so i've added `file = request.files.getlist('file')` before the flash message and redirect, and it worked!