# Upload file larger than MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH in Flask results connection reset

Tags: browser, flask

I'm trying to limit upload file size, I set app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] to the maximum value I want,

I used this code to display the error.

```
@app.errorhandler(413)
def request_entity_too_large(error):
    return 'File Too Large', 413
```

When using curl, the error displayed correctly.
I checked using Firefox/Safari, in both I get browser error of connection dropped/reset.

Firefox

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Safari

```
Can't open the page
...server unexpectedly dropped the connection...
```

server log in all of those requests

```
192.168.1.1 - - [23/May/2015 15:50:34] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 413 -
```

Why the error doesn't display correctly?

Comment: I think this is the problem with flask dev-server. How are you running your application?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue related to Flask's development server, you needn't worry about it. Run the application with production server will solve this problem.

In [this snippet](https://web.archive.org/web/20180302044355/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/) that posted by Armin Ronacher, he said:

> You might notice that if you start not accessing .form or .files on incoming POST requests, some browsers will honor this with a connection reset message. This can happen if you start rejecting uploads that are larger than a given size.
>
> Some WSGI servers solve that problem for you, others do not. For instance the builtin Flask webserver is pretty dumb and will not attempt to fix this problem.

See update [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66243421/5511849).